# Evaluating $\ln(\cos x))$ using Taylor expansion

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, taylor-expansion

> Evaluate $\ln(\cos x)$ at $x_0=0$ and with the order of $n=4$.

Noticing that $\ln(\cos x) = \ln(1+ \cos x - 1)$ we can use $\ln(1+x)$ Taylor series.

Now, I've read I should use:
$$\ln(1+x) = x - \frac{x^2}{2} + R_2(x)$$
$$\cos x -1 = -\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + R_4(x)$$

**Questions:**

1. If the demand was $n=4$, why did the author expand $\ln(1+x)$ for only two terms?
2. Following the author's way, how to plug $\cos x$ evaluation?

$$\ln(1+\cos x -1) = -\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + R_4(x) - \frac{\left(-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + R_4(x) \right)^2}{2} + R_2(-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4!} + R_4(x))$$

Is this what I should do? Because it's getting kinda messy..

Comment: The Taylor series for $\cos x - 1$ is already quadratic, so adding the cubic term for $\ln(1 + u)$ would mean evaluating a term $\frac{1}{3}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2} + \cdots\right)^3$, which is $-\frac{1}{24} x^6 + \cdots$, so this term is too high order to contribute.

Comment: Is the answer $-x^2-2x^4+\cdots$, by the way?

Comment: Almost. The answer is $P_4(x) = \frac{-x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{12}$

Comment: "..is already quadratic": So why not expanding $\ln(1+x)$ for only one term?

Comment: you should be using different unknowns, now the $x$ in the $\ln$ expansion is different from the $x$ in $\cos x$

Answer (score 2, accepted):

So far so good---the key observations remaining are:

1. In the contribution from the $u^2$ term of $\ln (1 + u)$, we can see that the only way to get a term of order $\leq 4$ in $x$ is $-\tfrac{1}{2}\left(-\frac{x^2}{2}\right)^2 = -\frac{x^4}{8}$.
2. The term $R_2\left(-\frac{x^2}{2} + \cdots\right)$ is already order $6$ in $x$, and so does not contribute to the Taylor polynomial of order $4$.

Applying these facts to simplify the second and third terms gives that the polynomial you seek is
$\left(-\frac{x^2}{2} + \frac{x^4}{4!}\right) - \left(\frac{x^4}{8}\right)
=      -\frac{x^2}{2} - \frac{x^4}{12}$.

Comment: Thanks a lot! I've understood it completely.